# Search for a branch name using wildcards

Tags: git, bash

A git repo I am working with has over a hundred remote branches, if not hundreds of them.

I'd like to be able to search for a particular branch whose name I know.

Is it possible to search for a specific branch using its name?

I also observe that many other branches have similar names or start with the same name as the branch I am looking for. For e.g. if I am looking for a branch named `foo-bar`, there are also branches like these:

```
foo-bar
foo-bar-really
foo-bar-nice
nice-foo-bar
foobar-nice
nice-foobar
foo-bar-okay
foo-bar-2.1
```

Is it possible to use wildcards or even regular expressions on the git bash command line to locate a branch? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the word-boundary anchors, in any version of `grep` you have installed

```
<git-command-listing-repos> | grep '^foo-bar$'
```

An excerpt from this [regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) page,

> Anchors
>
> [..] Anchors do not match any characters. They match a position. `^` matches at the start of the string, and `$` matches at the end of the string.[..]

---

An obvious temptation in similar cases would be to use the `-w` flag in `grep` to match the word as such. The fact is it *won't work*. It is mostly meant for matching the *pattern* as a *whole* on a line and *NOT* matching the entire line as such, for which you need the anchors.